# Frequency Dependent Absorption According to Wu

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, quantum-optics, laser-interaction

I was reading the paper "[Theory of strong-field attosecond transient absorption](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0953-4075/49/6/062003/meta)" by Wu, and he says that the difference in energy of a material interacting with an electromagnetic field (what it absorbs or emits) is

$$ \Delta E = 2e\int_{0}^{+\infty}\omega\mathrm{Im}\left[\tilde{{\varepsilon}}^{*}(\omega)\cdot\tilde{\left\langle \mathbf{r}\right\rangle }(\omega)\right]\frac{d\omega}{2\pi}, $$

where $ \tilde{{\varepsilon}} $ is the fourier transform of the electric field and $ \tilde{\left\langle \mathbf{r}\right\rangle }(\omega) $ is the Fourier transform of the expected position.

Then, the total incident energy is given by

$$ E_{i}=-\frac{\epsilon_{0}c}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\left|\tilde{{\varepsilon}}(\omega)\right|^{2}d\omega\oint_{S}\left[\left(\hat{\mathbf{k}}\times\hat{\mathbf{n}}\right)\times\hat{\mathbf{n}}\right]\cdot d\mathbf{a} $$

for a monochromatic beam (he doesn't say this but I think it makes sense).

I agree with these two points. But then he proceeds to say that the energy absorbed per frequency is

$$ \hbar \omega N(\omega) = 2e\omega\mathrm{Im}\left[\tilde{{\varepsilon}}^{*}(\omega)\cdot\tilde{\left\langle \mathbf{r}\right\rangle }(\omega)\right], $$

where $ N(\omega) $ is the difference between photons absorbed and emitted density, meaning,

$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty} N(\omega) = \Delta N, $$

$ \Delta N $ being the net number of absorbed and emitted photons.

Although it is very suggestive from the first equation that this is true, I should be able to get to this expression by taking a derivative, no? It seems that for now this isn't more than a conjecture.

The same for the spectral flux that he defines has $ \left|\tilde{{\varepsilon}}(\omega)\right|^{2} $.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you for your patience!